# Drag the Range of a UI Input Range Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, range, user-input

```
<---------[]=====================================[]-------->

0         10                                     90       100
```

I need an input range slider with two handles to select a range, and ***the ability to drag the range*** (the equals signs in the above diagram). So, in the above example, start=10 and end=90, and it is dragged left by shifting the entire line between the two handles:

```
<[]=====================================[]------------------>

0                                       80                 100
```

Now Start is 0 and End is 80, accomplished without dragging the handles.

What library offers this functionality?

Thank you.

Comment: @Dave Jarvis I'm working on my own custom one right now. Gotta run but if you want  to take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/EXpse/45/  Lemme know if it needs to be a framework or if something custom like that will do.

Comment: @Thomas - Looks like it needs some work. To fit his needs I recommend modifying the existing jQuery UI slider to meet his requirement.

Comment: i created an extension for this. see my answer.

Comment: @Justin Ethier, @Dave Jarvis yeah, i hadn't worked on it much. I was just showing it's possible without TOO much trouble to roll your own.

Answer (score 48):

### Overview

[jQuery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range) widget extension for a `rangeDrag` feature. This feature allows the user to drag the entire range at once, rather than having to drag the handles to move the range.

#### Code

https://gist.github.com/3758297

```
(function( $, undefined ) {

$.widget("ui.dragslider", $.ui.slider, {

    options: $.extend({},$.ui.slider.prototype.options,{rangeDrag:false}),

    _create: function() {
      $.ui.slider.prototype._create.apply(this,arguments);
      this._rangeCapture = false;
    },

    _mouseCapture: function( event ) { 
      var o = this.options;

      if ( o.disabled ) return false;

      if(event.target == this.range.get(0) && o.rangeDrag == true && o.range == true) {
        this._rangeCapture = true;
        this._rangeStart = null;
      }
      else {
        this._rangeCapture = false;
      }

      $.ui.slider.prototype._mouseCapture.apply(this,arguments);

      if(this._rangeCapture == true) {  
          this.handles.removeClass("ui-state-active").blur();   
      }

      return true;
    },

    _mouseStop: function( event ) {
      this._rangeStart = null;
      return $.ui.slider.prototype._mouseStop.apply(this,arguments);
    },

    _slide: function( event, index, newVal ) {
      if(!this._rangeCapture) { 
        return $.ui.slider.prototype._slide.apply(this,arguments);
      }

      if(this._rangeStart == null) {
        this._rangeStart = newVal;
      }

      var oldValLeft = this.options.values[0],
          oldValRight = this.options.values[1],
          slideDist = newVal - this._rangeStart,
          newValueLeft = oldValLeft + slideDist,
          newValueRight = oldValRight + slideDist,
          allowed;

      if ( this.options.values && this.options.values.length ) {
        if(newValueRight > this._valueMax() && slideDist > 0) {
          slideDist -= (newValueRight-this._valueMax());
          newValueLeft = oldValLeft + slideDist;
          newValueRight = oldValRight + slideDist;
        }

        if(newValueLeft < this._valueMin()) {
          slideDist += (this._valueMin()-newValueLeft);
          newValueLeft = oldValLeft + slideDist;
          newValueRight = oldValRight + slideDist;
        }

        if ( slideDist != 0 ) {
          newValues = this.values();
          newValues[ 0 ] = newValueLeft;
          newValues[ 1 ] = newValueRight;

          // A slide can be canceled by returning false from the slide callback
          allowed = this._trigger( "slide", event, {
            handle: this.handles[ index ],
            value: slideDist,
            values: newValues
          } );

          if ( allowed !== false ) {
            this.values( 0, newValueLeft, true );
            this.values( 1, newValueRight, true );
          }
          this._rangeStart = newVal;
        }
      }



    },


    /*
    //only for testing purpose
    value: function(input) {
        console.log("this is working!");
        $.ui.slider.prototype.value.apply(this,arguments);
    }
    */
});

})(jQuery);
```

#### Example

http://jsfiddle.net/omnosis/Swd9S/

#### Usage

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.slider.custom.js"></script>
...
<div id="slider"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function(){
// Slider
$('#slider').dragslider({
    animate: true,   // Works with animation.
    range: true,     // Must have a range to drag.
    rangeDrag: true, // Enable range dragging.
    values: [30, 70]        
});
});
```

Comment: +1 for the nice work! We ought to see about issuing a pull request for this on https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui - maybe they would add it to a future release (?)

Comment: No problem, I hope their team will be receptive :)

Comment: Good stuff! One little note of caution, though: for the code "as is", the last closing curly brace } prior to the end comments has a comma after it, which will generate a javascript error, depending on the browser you are using.

Comment: this is awesome, thank you. two bits for other users: for those using with require.js, you can save this extension as its own file and shim similar to jquery-ui: `'jquery-ui-dragslider': { deps: ['jquery-ui'], exports: "$" }` and, be sure you call methods within your dragslider as `$('#slider').dragslider()`, not `slider()`, or you'll get a jquery-ui error about the component not being initialized.

Comment: Is this code available for newer version(1.10.3) of jquery.ui.slider.js? Can these changes be pulled into git?

Comment: Works perfectly (thank you!) except in Opera - grabs the nearest handle and resizes instead.. ?

Comment: I use this implementation, it works fine with mouse. How could I trigger the slide effect to go right or left with right and left keys respectively?

Comment: @ericsoco Can you explain the second bit a bit please. I can't call any getter or setter on `$('#slider').dragslider()` but have no problem with`$('#slider').slider()` caling ` $( "#slider" ).on( "slidechange", function( event, ui ) {console.log("changed");} );` Thanks in advance

Comment: To answer my question for anyone stuck, events like `.on("change", function(){});` will now be `.on("dragslider change", function(){});`. The name of the custom plugin is concatanated to the name of the event.

Answer (score 5):

[noUiSlider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/) offers this feature. You can use it by setting the [`behaviour`option](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/behaviour-option/). It allows for both fixed and user-changeable ranges. There are no dependencies on jQueryUI, and if you prefer Zepto over jQuery: that works too.

[image]

**Disclosure:** I am the plugin author.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try [jQRangeSlider](http://ghusse.github.com/jQRangeSlider/), take a look at the [demo](http://ghusse.github.com/jQRangeSlider/demo.html).

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you have a look a the [jQuery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention: I need to be able to drag the range across the slider.

Comment: The drag functionality is not part of the jQuery UI Slider.

Comment: @Dave - I know, I answered his question before he added that requirement.

Comment: But that said, it is probably possible to modify the slider to support dragging the range. And the jQuery UI developers have discussed adding this feature.

Answer (score 1):

You might try checking out the [jQuery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range)

The link above demonstrates the "range" selector feature, which is what you're looking for, but there are lots of other ways to use it as well.

Comment: What are the other ways? The jQuery UI Slider doesn't support dragging the range across the slider, as far as I can tell.

Comment: It has a range, yes, but no way to drag the range itself. You must drag the end-points of the range.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the drag + drop triggers to the `$('.ui-slider-range')` element 
OR
 add you own event to the `$('.ui-slider-range')` element that just trigger the events on the `$('.ui-slider-handle')`

Comment: This is the approach I'm using as it's a bit cleaner, but you do have to provide some management of the handles when the slider is dragged.  Setting the ui.values[0] and [1] are the most direct way but your implementation will determine how you determine these values.  I've used a pageX and slider.left comparison in combination with a set tick-width to determine how many ticks to move the values when dragging.  YMMV.