# Extend jQuery UI slider to make range draggable

Tags: jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I was wondering if anyone had any advice or examples for how to extend the jQuery UI slider to make the range draggable? Basically what I want it something similar to [this](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range), but I'd like to be able to grab the gray bar and drag it to adjust the range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a widget extension available [here](https://gist.github.com/omnosis/3758297)
(see [Drag the Range of a UI Input Range Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955343/drag-the-range-of-a-ui-input-range-slider/6095941#6095941) for more detail)