# Display value range with jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I am working on some jQuery UI sliders and I was wondering is there a way to display a range of values instead of just single values. Such as 10-20, 20-30, 30-40 instead of just 10,20,30,40? I would really appreciate any help on this. I know there is a range slider in the API, but I am trying to get it to snap to the range increments.

[Here is a jsfiddle for a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/pbpyrojust/SCNGa/1/)

```
$(function() {
//age range function
$("#ageRangeSlider").slider({
  value: 10,
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  step: 10,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#yourAgeRange").val(ui.value);
  }
});
$("#yourAgeRange").val($("#ageRangeSlider").slider("value"));
});

<p>
  <label for="yourAgeRange">Your age range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="yourAgeRange" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
<div id="ageRangeSlider"></div>
```

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

Comment: I want it to snap to the increments. Let me clarify in the posting.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SCNGa/2/

Comment: i don't think its any different you just need to specify the range:true and starting positions

Answer (score 2):

Add range and starting values to the slider

```
  values:[50,100],
  range:true,
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SCNGa/2/)

**Update:** OP wants the whole slider range to move when you drag a handle. I found [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955343/drag-the-range-of-a-ui-input-range-slider/6095941#6095941) and [modified his code to get it working](http://jsfiddle.net/Swd9S/150/)... See the [JSBin](http://jsfiddle.net/Swd9S/150/)

Comment: That does work, but then there are two toggles on the slider. Is there any way to have just one while keeping the range?

Comment: events are not updating as I would expect. here's something that does what you want, although it allows you to adjust the range ends, if you drag the range in the middle the two ends move with it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955343/drag-the-range-of-a-ui-input-range-slider/6095941#6095941

Comment: ok I got it http://jsfiddle.net/Swd9S/150/ Don't hesitate to give the other guy a +1. I gave him one as well.

Comment: Thanks so much. I love stackoverflow and everyone that helps people like me on here!

Comment: After looking at that fiddle it does not snap. It would be nice to have it snap to the ranges.

Comment: Justin, you have to add the step value back in... (http://jsfiddle.net/Swd9S/151/)