# Is it possible to combine jquery-ui range slider with scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I would like to create a jquery-ui slider which is a combination of the "range slider" and "slider scrollbar" examples. Is this possible?

So it would have 3 manipulation points as below:

[image]

I want to use the slider to control a canvas. If you move an end it would zoom in/out of the canvas. If you slide the whole bar it would pan.

Comment: Yes..this is possible..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question: Yes, this is possible. To answer the underlying but inevitable "How", please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6095941/4762528).

Comment: Awesome. I did search before posting but didn't find that, nails it.